# Model Uploader Error

Tags: autodesk-forge

At Autodesk University we were able to use the forge API to use a model that was in models.autodesk.io and show it in a web page via the viewer API.

I want to be able to upload our own .rvt file to use so I can make a more contextually meaningful demo for my company.

The upload fails every time at the end with an error that just says "???".

I asked our folks to make sure there were no links in the file and its pretty light weight so I am not sure why it fails.

I tried to use the model derivative API "manually" via a series of REST calls (using POSTman) with no luck either but a little bit more info on my response:

```
{
"type": "manifest",
"hasThumbnail": "false",
"status": "failed",
"progress": "complete",
"region": "US",
"urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6d2VndGVzdGJ1Y2tldC9Pd2luZ3NNaWxscy5ydnQ",
"version": "1.0",
"derivatives": [
    {
        "name": "OwingsMills.rvt",
        "hasThumbnail": "false",
        "status": "failed",
        "progress": "complete",
        "messages": [
            {
                "type": "error",
                "code": "Revit-UnsupportedFileType",
                "message": "<message>The file is not a Revit file or is not a supported version.</message>"
            },
            {
                "type": "error",
                "message": "Possibly recoverable warning exit code from extractor: -536870935",
                "code": "TranslationWorker-RecoverableInternalFailure"
            }
        ],
        "outputType": "svf"
    }
]
```

}

Update:
Tried by converting my file to .ifc and received an even more cryptic error message...see my json response below:

```
{
"type": "manifest",
"hasThumbnail": "false",
"status": "failed",
"progress": "complete",
"region": "US",
"urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6d2VndGVzdGJ1Y2tldC9Pd2luZ3NNaWxscy5pZmM",
"version": "1.0",
"derivatives": [
    {
        "name": "LMV Bubble",
        "hasThumbnail": "false",
        "status": "failed",
        "progress": "complete",
        "messages": [
            {
                "type": "error",
                "message": "Unrecoverable exit code from extractor: -1073741829",
                "code": "TranslationWorker-InternalFailure"
            }
        ],
        "outputType": "svf"
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The Model Derivative API doesn't support every version of Revit file. In my experience it has only support current and 2 previous Revit versions.

Have you tried re-saving the file with a more recent version of Revit ?

Comment: Thanks, we tried that.  There must be something with our file...  We tried older versions of Revit as well as saving as an .ifc file and all those have failed.  The Revit file works and the ifc file is viewable via other 3rd party ifc viewers.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working.  Had a designer author in 2016 and it worked this time. Thanks.